# Wordpress ask user's their desired role as a dropdown menu while registration

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a custom field to the Wordpress registration form without using any plugins. I want to add a dropdown menu with user-roles ( some roles I have created). Once the registration is complete the user should not have the ability to change their roles ( only admin can do that, selecting role as admin should not be allowed).
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not likely that someone will help you without posting some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: There is a similar question here. You can modify it accordingly to your needs. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290987/add-role-selector-to-custom-registration-page

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you do not intend to use plugins, but you nevertheless use a theme, be it implemented by your team or some widely available theme. In any case, that theme has an implementation for your registration, so:

## Find the registration form

Make sure that you find out where the registration form is.

## Add a field to the form

Be it in a CMS editor or in a PHP/HTML file you must be able to edit it and add a field

## Find the code which runs when a registration is posted

Again, you need to seek and find.

## Enhance your functionalities which save fields

You will need to track and save the posted value

## Change the database schema

You will need to do some changes on the MySQL schema in order to support the new field on database-level.